# How to convert string to list<string> type

Tags: c#

```
foreach (string Tablename in uniqueFields)
{
    List<string> TblName = Tablename;//here the problem

    TblName = new List<string>();

    Console.WriteLine("children of :" + TblName);
    foreach (string TableAssociatedValue in fields)
    {
        if (TableAssociatedValue.Contains(Tablename.Trim()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TableAssociatedValue);
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: And what problem would that be? what have you tried/researched? Please read [ask]

Comment: Are you surprised `string` isn't assignable to a `List<string>`?

Comment: i want Tablename value should be copied to TblName..tats it

Comment: What have you researched? adding to a list should be very easy to search for. Although, I don't understand why you need the list at all, its scope is only for that foreach loop and you never really need it in there

Comment: Where are you using `TblName`? Note your `Console.WriteLine` won't work as you expect either, printing out a `List<T>` will yield its class name.

Comment: i ll clear more,first foreach loop gives the tablenames(list) and second foreach loop adds the elements into that tables(list).

Comment: if (TableAssociatedValue.Contains(Tablename.Trim()))
        {
           TblName.Add(TableAssociatedValue);
        }

Comment: I'll try to be more clear too, [ask] is there to show you what is expected of a question, stack overflow isn't there to replace google it is there to complement it, you should try to show what you have tried/ what you have researched, and why what you have found doesn't solve your problem

Comment: In simple words: don't use `List<string>`. Just use `Tablename` directly in the `Console.Writeline` and remove the line `TblName`. Are you maybe confused because uniqueFields is a list? The `foreach` already takes care of converting it to strings by enumerating it.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `List<string`> in your case. Just use `Tablename` directly since it contains what is required:

```
foreach (string Tablename in uniqueFields)
{
    // not required List<string> TblName = Tablename;//here the problem

    // doesn't make sense, and is not required TblName = new List<string>();

    //Console.WriteLine("children of :" + TblName); // use the line below instead
    Console.WriteLine("children of :" + Tablename);
    foreach (string TableAssociatedValue in fields)
    {
        if (TableAssociatedValue.Contains(Tablename.Trim()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TableAssociatedValue);
        }
    }       
}
```

Where you confused by `uniqueFields` which could be a `List<string>`? Don't be: the `foreach` construct is already enumerating each `string` in your list and will return each one as a string assigned to `Tablename` inside the loop. As a consequence you are not anymore required to work with the List itself, you can directly use `Tablename` as `string`.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign as

```
List<string> TblName=new List<string>{Tablename};
```

Comment: Always try to give an explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string Tablename in uniqueFields)
{
   List<string> TblName = new List<string>();
   // <Start Changes>
   TblName.Add(Tablename);
   // <End Changes>
   Console.WriteLine("children of :" + TblName);
   foreach (string TableAssociatedValue in fields)
   {
       if (TableAssociatedValue.Contains(Tablename.Trim()))
       {
          Console.WriteLine(TableAssociatedValue);
       }
   }       
}
```

As already mentioned, you cannot assign a value of type `string` to a value of type `List<String>`. How do you think should this even be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a list `List<string>` to a `string` - you have to add the string to the list

```
List<string> TblName=new List<string>{Tablename};
```

But you are setting `TblName` to an empty list just after, which makes no sense.